# Add a continuous legend to a heat map in R (base R preferred because ggplot is not working)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am generating a heatmap using base R because when I use ggplot, I create a plot that is not correct.

```
masterdf<-structure(list(Rf = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 
0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 
0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 
0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1), AbsMet = c(91202.94, 77277.491, 
55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 
10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 
45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 
5292.822, 1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 
36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 
1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 
26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911, 
91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 
18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911, 91202.94, 
77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 
14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 
55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 
10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 
45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 
5292.822, 1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 
36075.663, 26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 
1782.911, 91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 
26403.696, 18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911, 
91202.94, 77277.491, 55406.172, 45767.041, 36075.663, 26403.696, 
18857.326, 14186.311, 10353.254, 5292.822, 1782.911), RelMet = c(2.011, 
1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 
0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 
1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 
1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 
1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 
1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 
2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 
1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 
1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 
1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 
1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 0.993, 2.011, 
1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 1.073, 1.007, 
0.993, 2.011, 1.845, 1.632, 1.504, 1.411, 1.276, 1.207, 1.123, 
1.073, 1.007, 0.993), Anq = c(0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 
0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 
0.004, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.004, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005), Simq = c(0.006, 
0.006, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.009, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.01, 0.009, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 
0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.01, 0.011, 0.009, 0.008, 
0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.009, 0.009, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 
0.01, 0.009, 0.008, 0.009, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 
0.007, 0.006, 0.01, 0.01, 0.009, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 
0.007, 0.007, 0.006, 0.006, 0.01, 0.009, 0.009, 0.009, 0.008, 
0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.006, 0.007, 0.01, 0.009, 0.009, 
0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.01, 
0.009, 0.009, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.006, 
0.006, 0.009, 0.009, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 
0.007, 0.007, 0.006), AbsDif = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 
0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0, 0, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.003, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001, 
0.001, 0.006, 0.006, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.005, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003, 0.004, 
0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.003, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001), RelDif = c(1.5, 
1.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 1.25, 1, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.667, 0.333, 0.333, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.75, 
0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 1.2, 1.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 1, 1, 
0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.2), theta = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 
0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 0.68, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 
1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 
1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 
2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 2.12, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 
2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 
3.08, 3.08, 3.08, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 
3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 
4.04, 4.04, 4.04, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 
4.52, 4.52, 4.52, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c("tableofvaluesRf0theta0.2", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.1theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0.2theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta0.2", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0.6theta0.2", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.7theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0.8theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta0.2", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta0.2", "tableofvaluesRf0theta0.68", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta0.68", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta0.68", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta0.68", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta0.68", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta0.68", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta0.68", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta0.68", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta0.68", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta0.68", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta0.68", "tableofvaluesRf0theta1.16", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta1.16", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta1.16", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta1.16", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta1.16", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta1.16", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta1.16", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta1.16", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta1.16", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta1.16", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta1.16", "tableofvaluesRf0theta1.64", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta1.64", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta1.64", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta1.64", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta1.64", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta1.64", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta1.64", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta1.64", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta1.64", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta1.64", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta1.64", "tableofvaluesRf0theta2.12", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta2.12", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta2.12", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta2.12", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta2.12", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta2.12", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta2.12", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta2.12", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta2.12", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta2.12", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta2.12", "tableofvaluesRf0theta2.60", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta2.60", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta2.60", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta2.60", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta2.60", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta2.60", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta2.60", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta2.60", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta2.60", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta2.60", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta2.60", "tableofvaluesRf0theta3.08", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta3.08", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta3.08", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta3.08", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta3.08", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta3.08", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta3.08", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta3.08", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta3.08", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta3.08", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta3.08", "tableofvaluesRf0theta3.56", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta3.56", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta3.56", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta3.56", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta3.56", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta3.56", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta3.56", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta3.56", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta3.56", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta3.56", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta3.56", "tableofvaluesRf0theta4.04", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta4.04", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta4.04", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta4.04", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta4.04", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta4.04", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta4.04", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta4.04", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta4.04", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta4.04", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta4.04", "tableofvaluesRf0theta4.52", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta4.52", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta4.52", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta4.52", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.4theta4.52", "tableofvaluesRf0.5theta4.52", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.6theta4.52", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta4.52", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta4.52", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta4.52", 
"tableofvaluesRf1theta4.52", "tableofvaluesRf0theta5", "tableofvaluesRf0.1theta5", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.2theta5", "tableofvaluesRf0.3theta5", "tableofvaluesRf0.4theta5", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.5theta5", "tableofvaluesRf0.6theta5", "tableofvaluesRf0.7theta5", 
"tableofvaluesRf0.8theta5", "tableofvaluesRf0.9theta5", "tableofvaluesRf1theta5"
), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(masterdf,aes(x=RelMet,y=theta,fill=AbsDif))+
 geom_tile()+scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high="darkred",name="Absolute Difference")
```

ggplot produces this
[image]

So instead I create a heatmap using base R, which produces the correct output, however, I cannot find a way to add a continuous legend to this graph similar to the output of the ggplot.

```
heatmap1<-masterdf[,c("RelMet","theta","AbsDif")]
heatmap1_matrix<-heatmap1 %>% 
  spread(key = theta, value = AbsDif)%>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  column_to_rownames(var="RelMet")%>%
  as.matrix
  

plot1<-heatmap(heatmap1_matrix,Colv=NA,Rowv = NA, scale="column")
```

[image]

Could somebody helpfully suggest how to add a continuous legend to the base R plot, or alternatively explain how to fix my ggplot heatmap?

Many thanks.

Comment: ggplot is making that plot because RelMet is a continuous variable and the spacing is uneven. If you convert RelMet to a factor, it should work as you expect

Comment: As Richard commented, turing RelMet into a factor can be done like this `ggplot(masterdf,aes(x=as.factor(RelMet),y=theta,fill=AbsDif)) + geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high="darkred",name="Absolute Difference")`